# Find the volume of the parallelepiped.

Tags: calculus

Find the volume of the parallelepiped having vectors $a=(1,4,-7)$, $b=(2,-1,4)$, and $c=(0,-9,18)$ as adjacent edges. What conclusions can you make about vectors $a$,$b$, and $c$?

So to solve this I used the triple scalar product and got the equation $18i-144j-126k$ and the volume to be $192.1874$ units cubed. Is this correct? & What conclusions can I make about the vectors? I was thinking that $A$ and $B$ are orthogonal?

Comment: If the volume is non-zero, the vectors are not coplanar, A and B are not orthogonal as their dot product ($-30$) is not zero.

Comment: How will the triple scalar product allow you to calculate the volume of a parallelepiped? That's just silly.

Answer (score 2):

We use that $$V=|a\cdot ( b  \times c)|=|(1,4,7)\cdot (18,-36,-18)|=0$$
This means the vectors are coplanar.

Answer (score 0):

The scalar triple product is zero, meaning that the edges are coplanar.

Answer (score 0):

Given three vectors $\vec{a}$, $\vec{b}$, $\vec{c}$, the volume is given by

> $$
> \left|
> \det
> \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
> a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\
> b_1 & b_2 & b_3 \\
> c_1 & c_2 & c_3
> \end{array}
> \right)
> \right|
> $$

Put in the values and you get

> $$
> \det
> \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
> 1 & 4 & -7 \\
> 2 & 1 & -4 \\
> 0 & -9 & 18
> \end{array}
> \right)
> = 0,
> $$

also known as the *scalar product triplet*.
So the volume is

> $$
> \left|
> \det
> \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
> 1 & 4 & -7 \\
> 2 & 1 & -4 \\
> 0 & -9 & 18
> \end{array}
> \right)
> \right|
> = 0.
> $$

You should get

> $$
> \det
> \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
> \hat{x} & \hat{y} & \hat{z} \\
> 2 & 1 & -4 \\
> 0 & -9 & 18
> \end{array}
> \right)
> = \big( -18 + 36 \big) \hat{x}
>    + \big( 0 - 36\big) \hat{y}
>    + \big( -18 \big) \hat{z}
> = 18 \hat{x} -36 \hat{y} -18 \hat{z}
> $$

So you end up with

> $$
> \big( 1 \hat{x} +  4 \hat{y} -7 \hat{z} \big) \cdot
> \big( 18 \hat{x} -36 \hat{y} -18 \hat{z} \big) = 18 - 144 + 126 = 0.
> $$

Comment: any chance someone can show the work as to how the triple scalar product is 0? I seem to get a different answer..

Comment: What steps did you perform?

Comment: I had (-18+36)i-(36-0)j+(-18+0)k then I got 18(1)i-36(4)j-18(-7)k and then I got 18i-144j-126k and then i put each term under a radical and squared each term..?

Answer (score 0):

first for scalar triple product we have 
\begin{align}
        \begin{vmatrix}
        1 & 4 & -7 \\
        2 & -1 & 4 \\
        0 & -9 & 18 \\
        \end{vmatrix}&=9\times\begin{vmatrix}
        1 &  -7 \\
        2 & 4 \\
        \end{vmatrix}+18\times\begin{vmatrix}
        1 &  4 \\
        2 & -1 \\
        \end{vmatrix}\\&=9(1\times 4+2\times 7)+18(-1-2\times 4)\\&=9\times 18+18\times(-9)\\&=0
\end{align}
scalar triple product should be a scalar so how did you get the vector $18i-144j-126k$?
because the scalar triple product is $0$ it shows that the parallelepiped that is formed by the three vectors does not have volume and so the three vectors are coplanar

Suppose that we have three vectors $a=(a_1,a_2,a_3),b=(b_1,b_2,b_3),c=(c_1,c_2,c_3)$the formulas to calculate the outer product of two of these vectors and the triple product of three vectors is as follows:
$$a\times b=\begin{vmatrix}
        i & j & k \\
        a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\
        b_1 & b_2 & b_3 \\
        \end{vmatrix}$$
$$a.(b\times c)=\begin{vmatrix}
        a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\
        b_1 & b_2 & b_3 \\
        c_1 & c_2 & c_3 \\
        \end{vmatrix}$$

Comment: any chance someone can show the work as to how the triple scalar product is 0? I seem to get a different answer..

Comment: I had 1(-18+36)i -4(36-0)j-7(-18+0)k

Comment: @Lil I will edit my answer to show why

Comment: so you complete the usual cross product with the first two columns and then multiply by the third? I always took the cross product of the last to columns then multiplied by the corresponding coefficient of the first column

Comment: @Lil have you studied about the determinant of 3-order and 2-order matrices so far? if not tell me to illustrate the answer another way. And remember because scalar triple product is of the form $a.(b\times c)$ meaning that we have an inner product between the vectors $a$ and $(b\times c)$it can never be a vector. the answer of a scalar triple product is always a scalar maybe you are mixing with outer product of two vectors?!

Comment: ok @Lil I'll add an edit to my answer to response your question

Comment: yeah I'm relatively new to the concept. My teacher went through the material really fast so I am trying to self-teach.